# Play sound if you hit a button

Tags: ios, objective-c, audio, freeze

I'm creating an iOS-based game and need some help. I'd like to write some code that plays a sound when a button on the screen is pressed. I have placed a big button over the whole Storyboard and used this to implement my sound file:

```
- (IBAction)sound; {
    CFBundleRef mainBundle = CFBundleGetMainBundle();
    CFURLRef soundFileURLRef;
    soundFileURLRef = CFBundleCopyResourceURL(mainBundle, (CFStringRef) @"hit1", CFSTR ("wav"), NULL);
    UInt32 soundID;
    AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID(soundFileURLRef, &soundID);
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundID);
}
```

If I start my application and I hit the screen, the sound plays but my whole display is frozen and I just see a frozen screen and play the pushbutton sound.

Does anyone know of a solution?

Thank you.

Comment: The display never becomes "unfrozen"? How can you be sure that it ever freezes?

Comment: i can touch the display and the sound plays but the display picture does not change

Comment: You might try putting a touch gesture recognizer on the screen instead of one large button? What type of interaction do you want to occur after the sound is played?

Comment: This is an iOS, not Objective-C question. Why do people always confuse the language with its libraries?

Answer (score 0):

Your screen is not responding because you have a button in top of it. Create a IBOutlet and connect it to your button. Then when the button is pressed, hide the button.

An example will be:

in your .h

```
IBOutlet UIButton *playBtn;
```

in your .m:

```
- (IBAction)sound {

CFBundleRef mainBundle = CFBundleGetMainBundle();
CFURLRef soundFileURLRef;
soundFileURLRef = CFBundleCopyResourceURL(mainBundle, (CFStringRef) @"hit1", CFSTR ("wav"), NULL);
UInt32 soundID;
AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID(soundFileURLRef, &soundID);
AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundID);

// Hide button when user presses the button

playBtn.hidden =YES;

}
```

Make sure you connect the IBOutlet in the Interface Builder to the button.

You can also try a UIGestureRecognizer to detect a tap on the screen.